# First image doesn't display in JS/JQ slidshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make a javascript slideshow using some javaquery the first image doesn't fade in like it should and so obviously none of the other images slide or out either. This is my first attempt at making one of these so I'm not quite sure why it isn't working I've looked over and over at the code to make sure I've spelled everything correctly and all the proper punctuation, but I guess I could still be missing something. Anyway my code.

HTML5

```
<head>
    <title>Home Styles</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon-logo-HS.ico"/>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/slider.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="Slider();" class="body">

            <div class="slider">
                <img id="1" src="Images/slide_image1.jpg" alt="TV Deals"/>
                <img id="2" src="Images/slide_image2.jpg" alt="Furniture Deals"/>
                <img id="3" src="Images/slide_image3.jpg" alt="Electronic Deals"/>
            </div>
```

CSS3

```
.slider {
    width: 990px;
    height: 270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-image: url('../Images/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.slider img{
    width: 990px;
    height: 270px;
    border: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

javascript

```
function Slider(){
    $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);

    var sc=$(".slider img").size();
    var count=2;

    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction: 'right'},500);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left', 500);

        if(count == sc){
            count = 1;
        }else{
            count = count + 1;  
        }
    }, 6500);
}
```

Comment: Are you leaving out some code or did you just not close the `<body>` tag?

Comment: I'm leaving out some code, the other code is just a header with a nav menu and the div is enclosed within a section tag, but I'm thinking that shouldn't affect the slideshow.

Comment: any errors in your console when you load the page?

Comment: no, I have a gif in the background that works as a loading symbol and that shows up and goes around and around. Just the fist image never fades in.

Comment: Also, in your `setInterval` function,  you are missing a closing bracket `}` on the parameter being passed to `.hide`  I would suggest creating a jsfiddle and testing it there first and seeing if errors are being returned as I've already identified 2 syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several things going on with your JS that might be the issue here. First off a quick JShint tells me there are some syntax errors (missing semicolons and the like). But I think the real issue is that you're using some of these methods with non default easings but not defining new ones.

For example `.hide()` doesn't have a 'slide' easing. http://api.jquery.com/hide/. I would read through the api for `.show()` and `.hide()` you probably need to replace them with `.animate()`

Here is a solution that may work for you: **[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/BACJE/)**

HTML:

```
  <div class="slider">
     <img id="1" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300&text=Slide1" alt="TV Deals"/>
     <img id="2" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300&text=Slide2" alt="Furniture Deals"/>
     <img id="3" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300&text=Slide3" alt="Electronic Deals"/>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    slider();
});

function slider(){
    var count = 1;

    $('#1').show();

    (function slide(){
        $('.slider img').hide();

        if (count > 3) {count = 1;} // makes this a loop

        $('#'+count).fadeIn('slow');
        count += 1;

        setTimeout(function () {
            slide();
        }, 5000);
    })();
}
```

I use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` because of personal preference (interval can overlap function calls). You could also remove the `.fadeIn()`in my example and replace it with `.animate()` to get that horizontal slide effect you wanted.

Comment: Well yours is obviously working in jsfiddle, but it's still not pulling in the first image in my work. I thank you for taking the time to try and help me though.

Comment: @SecretWalrus, if it's working in the fiddle, but not your local environment what I would do is comment out all of your code, and uncomment each bit individually and find where it's breaking. Since you know it should be working.

Comment: I'm thinking it's just not even touching my java at all, I've tried making a completely new site with nothing but my code and it still won't pull in my code. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but are you sure you're loading jQuery? Try going into the developer tools and seeing if there are any errors in the console etc.

Comment: I have no idea if I'm loading jQuery or not to be honest. Isn't that what these two lines of code do?

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's finally pulling in on the site it works as long as it's on .fadeIn(), but if I try .animate() like you said it stops pulling in the first image again. Sorry I really know know Jquery well at all this is my first time using it, can you please help?

Comment: Here is good cheat sheet for jQuery [http://oscarotero.com/jquery/](http://oscarotero.com/jquery/), here is the api for .animate() [http://api.jquery.com/animate/](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this in jsfiddle and removing all the extra stuff that jsfiddle doesn't want, I noticed you are missing a closing bracket.  I don't understand how you could not be getting console errors cause this is a syntax error:

```
function Slider() {
    $("#a1").show("fade",500);
    $("#a1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mF7wv/

Comment: fixed that error and it's still not pulling int he first image.

Comment: badAdviceGuy has a working solution, I would look at his example fiddle.  My solution and fiddle also work.  If you want us to troubleshoot your code for you, create a fiddle for us to test it on.